# Port configuration on Google APP Engine

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I'm moving my self hosted software to Google App Engine and have a major issue: something is blocking my requests to my MongoDB (I'm using ParseServer).

I tried many things: none is working

- Move to an internally hosted Google App Engine
- Move to a mLab (did both)
- Try the project locally (of course working)

So to summary the problem:
click this link: http://146.148.6.152:27017/jobninja and you should see an error. If you `curl` it from the server you get no result...

Same if you `telnet portquiz.net 27017` from the server you get no response...

Anyway, I'm not very familiar with Google App Engine but I tried to add the tcp:27017 to the firewall but doesn't change anything.

My questions are:

- Where can I get the confirmation that the port are blocking?
- Does the computer engine rules apply to the app engine instances?
- How can I define AppEngine rules?
- More generally, would be nice to find the beginning of a solution :)

Comment: App Engine does not currently provide a way to map static IP addresses to an application. In order to optimize the network path between an end user and an App Engine application, end users on different ISPs or geographic locations might use different IP addresses to access the same App Engine application. DNS might return different IP addresses to access App Engine over time or from different network locations.

Comment: You should try: <your app-id>.appspot.com/jobninja

Comment: Yeah fine, but that's not what it is about, I have no outgoing traffic to some ports...

Comment: Are you trying to set the port on your hosted (production) server?  Or the local dev server?  You cannot set the port in production.  Compute Engine allows you to set up dedicated (static) IP addresses, but GAE does not.  The rules are different.

Comment: I AM NOT TRYING TO SET THE PORT OF THE MACHINE, I am trying to access a remote port but it is blocked.

Comment: So App Engine will allow allow traffic into your App Engine instances on port 80/443.  Traffic inside of the GCE network between your GAE app and GCE instances should work fine.  Actually all outbound traffic should work fine.  You're not trying to host a MongoDB server in App Engine... are you?  Where is your MongoDB server sitting exactly?

Comment: Also, this guide should help on basics:  https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/resources/databases/mongodb

Comment: I solved it, thanks a lot for your help @GAEfan. I was a bit nervous and couldn't formulate the issue very well I guess

Comment: Thanks @JustinBeckwith, I know what you told me, I had other problem on my level to solve but there was a critical lack of doc. See answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it:

This is very weird that it didn't crash before but the `serverURL` of ParseServer was wrong and not set via environnement,

As a consequence: `CloudCode` which actually just pass request through Parse wasn't able to find the server to talk to... I found the error by looking at the Heroku config file of Parse-Server-Example.

So no problem with the ports or, at least, it was not the blocking problem

As a reminder for the readers of this post:

**SERVER_URL is very important for having `CloudCode` working!!!**